# lualatex batchmode is very noisy

Tags: luatex

I am using lualatex (luatex 0.95.0) like this:

```
lualatex --interaction=batchmode file.tex
```

and am getting copious output to the terminal, font stuff, information from other packages etc. lots more than luatex 0.8. Is there no way to make it really quiet short of the usual `>/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: are you sure you have a fully up to date texlive test install? running in batchmode on either lualatex from texlive 2015 and from texlive2016 test, I get the same output of about 13 lines

Comment: Yes, it's very noisy. But this should be raised on the luatex mailing list rather than here. The console output is the same as the log, which is wrong to begin with.

Comment: On the terminal I see (with a minimal document loading arial) only 3 lines when using batchmode (on windows).

Comment: I am using TL 2016 pretest and I think it's all up to date. I have never been able to suppress all luatex console with batchmode but with 0.95 it became a lot noisier. batchmode certainly cuts some things out but on a reasonably large document, I still get 400+ lines of output.

Comment: This sounds wrong. Either there is a bug in your binary or your document resets the mode. E.g. \scrollmode in the document would overwrite the command line option. What happens if you add \batchmode in the docu,ment?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there is no `\scrollmode` and adding `\batchmode` makes no difference. I just updated TL 2016 pretest and I get the same results: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu447uzi8lbrws6/out.txt?dl=0

Comment: It is probably related to this (which does not apply to the windows binaries according to the last message in the thread) http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-April/005893.html

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, this seems to be the same thing. I'll just wait for the real TL 2016 ... thanks for confirming. You might want to make that an answer - I think it would help others who are pretesting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a bug report

Comment: Fine by me although it might help users coming here as a first resort to know that it's a bug.

Comment: The last binary for TeX Live 2016 has fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes, looks much better now - same as before. It's still a bit annoying that there is no real batchmode, you still get `This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 restricted system commands enabled.

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 0.129 seconds` but that's always been the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably related to this reported bug (which does not apply to the windows binaries according to the last message in the thread)

http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-April/005893.html